# How to put a limit on the number of posts in a wordpress blog using php?

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I'm currently using this but when I click on "next page" it shows the same three posts on all the pages instead of showing the next 3 posts and so fourth.

```
<?php 
    global $query_string;
    query_posts ('posts_per_page=3');
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<p>?php the_time(); ?></p>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<p><?php the_tags(); ?></p>
```

```
<p><?php next_posts_link(); ?></p>
<p><?php previous_posts_link(); ?></p>
```

```
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>Silly monkey.</p>
```

Comment: Have you tried `paged`? https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#set-paged

Answer (score 0):

Pick up the paged variable and use it in your query.

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );
query_posts ('posts_per_page=3&paged=' . $paged);
```